# Set gravity of dynamic textview

Tags: android

I have created a text view dynamically.I want to set its gravity to right.I have used textview.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT) but its not working.When I am using it the text view is aligned to left direction only.How can I set the gravity of textview?I dont want to use setPadding().

```
textMore[i]=new TextView(this);
                    textMore[i].setGravity(Gravity.Right);
                    textMore[i].setText("more....");

                    textMore[i] .setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Comment: The width of the view is probably set to `wrap_content`, so the `TextView` is as wide as its content. You could set the `TextView`'s width to `match_parent` and still use `Gravity.Right`, or you could use `wrap_conten`t and use `LayoutParams` to set the `layout_gravity` to right

Comment: Your `TextView` is inside which layout ? Based on the Layout, create a `LayoutParam` for your `TextView` and set `layout_gravity` for that.

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE- Linear Layout that I have added dynamically is set to wrap content.So shuld I change it to match parent and then try to set gravity?

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE- I have used linear layout.I have also created a layout param as wrap content,wrap content. I have also set the gravity of layout also but still its not working.So should I have to set layout params as match parent?

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE- I have set layoutParams as MatchParent and wrap content and now setGravity() is working.

Comment: @AnushkaAgarwal your `LinearLayout` should be set to `match_parent`. Then you can set your `TextView` to `wrap_content` and use `LayoutParams` to set the layout gravity to right

Comment: Post your `LinearLayout` code which is parent to the `TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

you can't change alignment of TextView by `setGravity` , it changes the TextView contents alignment.

Comment: @Arash- Is there any way to set it?

Comment: @AnushkaAgarwal : change it's parent gravity or set layout_gravity for the TextView

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams textParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) textMore[i].getLayoutParams();
textParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
textMore[i].setLayoutParams(textParams);
```

and then add the view in your dynamic `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 0):

**If the parent of your text view is RelativeLayout**(Prefer this)

set : alignParentRight

**If the parent of your text view is LinearLayout**

set : setLayoutGravity(Gravity.Right)

or

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams textParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)textMore[i].getLayoutParams();
textParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
textMore[i].setLayoutParams(textParams);
```

**setGravity(Gravity.Right)** ==> This property will align the text inside your textView, rather than aligning the view in its parent.

Comment: Try to find the cause for your nullPointerException, and hit it!
I guess the basic idea must be clear, now its upto you.

Good luck

Comment: @Eu.Dr.: As the OP is creating the `TextView` dynamically, so instead of creating `LayoutParam` using `getLayoutParams()`, you should write `LinearLayout.LayoutParams textParams=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);`.

Comment: @Eu.Dr.- Alrite. I will try it.

Comment: @SpringBreaker- oh yes.. u r right..Nw its not crashing but its not setting my textview to right,instead its in left direction.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly set your textView Width property to fill parent then you can set it gravity to right
if you are using linear layout